# protect images from being copied

Tags: javascript, php, html, image

Im looking for reliable solutions to protect images from being copied...
My customer (photographer) would like to avoid customers copying her pictures without buying them.

I was thinking about mixing these techniques:

---

### PHP self-made expiration

images are loaded from a PHP script reading from the image file, in the request I bundle the request timestamp and filename. if the timestamp is very close to the actual timestamp (both timestamps are generated on the same server, so no time config issues) the request is created on page generation. For example: in the generated HTML, I have some img tag like:

So when the users wants to copy the image source from source code, the image.php script won't answer as there is a delay between page generation and image request...

### No caching

If I send a No cache header, **I suppose the browser doesn't caches/stores the file on the client computer?**

---

Now that's the basic idea..
Users don't have the original file name so can't access them directly..
With this solution, I can even watermark them on the fly or resize them

Users could still print screen them, there are 2 types of printscreens, those that put them in the clipboard, and those that save a file.

Would there be a solution, I was thinking about some sort of javascript side onkeydown and detecting the printscreen touch, or shift+alt+cmd+[1-4] on Mac combination and blank out imagesbefore any action is taken.. **is this possible, more or less reliable and how?**

Another partial idea I had was to clear the clipboard on an interval or some action, but this is annoying for people, doesn't work for desktop saved screen captures, and maybe doesn't works on all browsers.

**Any other idea?**

So where to go from here?
This is a practical question, I know people could take a picture of their screen after all or use a HDMI cable to capturing device.. but seriously, this is overkill, no one will do this for such pictures, we're not talking about top secret classified documents...

Comment: Add a watermark, you can't stop a user from getting the picture off the site.

Comment: What stops me inspecting the element in Chrome Developer Tools (or FireBug if you're so inclined) and accessing the link of the image, or saving it via that?

Comment: There's no reliable way to protect images. If the image is displayed in a browser you can copy it. You can make it a bit more difficult, but it's always going to be possible.

Comment: Watermarks and other deliberate artifacts are really the only option.  If somebody can see the picture, they can copy the picture.  No matter what efforts you put into your code, they can always just take a screenshot.

Comment: Use lower res images with watermarks for the samples. When they purchase the images they get the full resolution image.

Comment: (Related anecdote)... I was once consulting for a company which handled medical data, and they wanted a system similar to this.  Users should be able to see documents and other data, but shouldn't be able to copy it.  (Not a website, a smart client app, so different technologies.)  They contracted another firm for that part, spent 7 figures on a solution, and were very proud with what they had.  While demoing it, I took out my phone and took a picture of the screen.  Data... copied.  They didn't like that.

Comment: You can disable javascript. Even with javascript enabled, you can screenshot the desktop while being in a different active application (since you are not in the browser, the javascript won't trigger on buttons pressed for screenshot taking).

Comment: When uploading my own photos, I use a lower resolution image for showing, and a higher resolution for selling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is my implementation:

First when calling an image during a page generation in php:

```
$reqinfo['id'] = $data[id];
$reqinfo['maxsize'] = 320;
$reqinfo['timestamp'] = time();
$reqinfo['base'] = false;

$encoded = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt(serialize($reqinfo), 'AES-128-CBC', 'martine',0,'fgrgfvcfghtfdrfg'));

echo'<div class="imagecontainer"><img src="photo.php?info='.$encoded.'" /></div>';
```

This already implement some restrictions in css and javascript on the imagecontainer class.
I send the image ID (or name) the maximum width or height and the request timestamp, all this encrypted in a request string sent to photo.php
base is ment to be true if image may bypass everything and be called like a plain image.

### photo.php

```
<?
//request info
$reqinfo = unserialize(openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($_GET[info]), 'AES-128-CBC', 'martine',0,'fgrgfvcfghtfdrfg'));

//image expired
if(time() - $reqinfo[timestamp] > 10){ exit(); }

//public image
if($reqinfo[base] == true){ readfile('img/'.$reqinfo[id].'.jpg'); exit(); }

//header cache
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

//check cache existance and send out
if(file_exists( 'img/'.$reqinfo[id].'_'.$reqinfo[maxsize].'.jpg')) { readfile('img/'.$reqinfo[id].'_'.$reqinfo[maxsize].'.jpg'); exit(); }

//source Image
$image_path = 'img/'.$reqinfo[id].'.jpg';
list($original_width, $original_height)= getimagesize($image_path); 
$srcImage = imagecreatefromjpeg( $image_path );
$ratio = $original_height/$original_width;


//create destination image holder
$destination_width = $reqinfo['maxsize'];
if($destination_width < 1) $destination_width = 1;
if($destination_width > $original_width)$destination_width = $original_width;
$destination_height = round($destination_width*$ratio);
if ($destination_height > $reqinfo['maxsize'])
{
    $destination_height = $reqinfo['maxsize'];
    $destination_width = round($destination_height/$ratio);
}
$targetImage = imagecreatetruecolor( $destination_width, $destination_height );
imagealphablending($targetImage,true);

//resample copy logo
imagecopyresampled( $targetImage, $srcImage, 
0, 0, 
0, 0, 
$destination_width, $destination_height, 
$original_width, $original_height );


// watermark
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('watermark.png');
imagesettile($targetImage, $watermark);
imagefilledrectangle($targetImage, 0, 0, $destination_width, $destination_height, IMG_COLOR_TILED);




//output
imagejpeg(  $targetImage, 'img/'.$reqinfo[id].'_'.$reqinfo[maxsize].'.jpg' );
imagejpeg(  $targetImage );
imagedestroy( $targetImage );


?>
```

*'martine' is a simple passphrase
img is obviously an non public path*

Hope this is more or less clear, basically this (in order):

- Decrypt the $reqinfo array
- check if imagerequest is fresh, if a user copies the urls and loads in another frame, no image will be loaded.
- Checks if the image can bypass resize and watermark and be sent to the browser
- Checks if a cached version exists to speed up process
- Recreates a resized version
- Add a watermark
- Saves a server cached version
- sends out the 'disposable' image

Hope this can helps someone...

Answer (score 3):

Anything displayed can be captured.  All solutions are from server side : adding a  watermark, or  using small low-resolution images for display.

Answer (score 3):

The general rule of thumb is: If it can be accessed with a browser, the user already has full access to it and can take it if they wish to do so. Example options:

### Option 1:

Prevent right clicking via JavaScript.

Won't work when user:

- Disables JavaScript and refreshes the page.
- Uses a screenshot tool.
- Manually inspects your HTML and finds the img src.

### Option 2:

Put image as the background image of a div.

Won't work when user:

- Uses a screenshot tool.
- Manually inspects your HTML/CSS and finds the img src.

### Option 3:

Use a watermark and/or a low res image.

Probably the best approach here. If your client is a photographer that wants to protect his/her work, displaying a low-res image and providing an option/link to purchase the hi-res version may be the best course of action. Adding a watermark may also dissuade visitors from taking the image free-of-charge as nobody wants to frame a picture that has a photographer's logo across the middle.

Comment: Is there any solution except for taking a screenshot if flash is used (preferably with an encrypted data stream)?

Comment: @JanDvorak There are swf decompilers out there.

Comment: if I find out that the flash uses, say, HTTPS or Diffie-Hellmann, then I'll need a live debugger or a cert that the flash applet will accept - or to reimplement / port / reuse the decoding stage (which may not be easy) - or pull up a full man in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

1. photographer mostly doing high quality pictures, so why not show on the web site low quality images and write on them "Demo" or something.
2. use flash to prevent from the users copy them.
3. encode your images into base64 and show them with canvas or svg.

Comment: base64 is a bad advice. I can steal that easily

Comment: well its not prefect solution, that's true.
but most of the user wont be able to steal, unless they tech users.

Comment: I'm pretty sure taking a screenshot does not require much technical knowledge - and both #2 and #3 are susceptible to that. I admit, though, that low-tech users usually don't know how to capture HTTP streams and decode them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 100% protection..

The client always can make for example a Screenshot from the image.
Or can get the Link to the image with the browser's code-inspector.

Add a watermark is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've experimented with various techniques: 1 is to divide the image into multiple images-- think about dividing an image up into say 16 different PNGs. Each image showing  say a 4x4 pixel or 10x10 pixel block of colored pixels, with 15 10x10 blocks being completely transparent. When you combine these images exactly on top of each other, the full image is displayed. Of course you can do it with only 2 images, or as many as you like. This will absolutely prevent someone from downloading the image.

Secondly, I've experimented with a similar technique, however, hiding and showing the images randomly, with most of them showing at any one time.. that way if someone screen captures it, it'll be only a part of the image.  Due to "persistence of vision" you should be able to see the image normally IF the framerate was high enough.. but currently, it really doesn't work well.

Lastly, you can combine these techniques with CSS filters and altered colored images-- think, rotate the hue on the source image, and use a filter to rotate it back. You can get crazy with all kinds of filters and mix-blend-modes to  craft a perfectly displayed image that cannot be downloaded and look anything like the original without reversing the technique.