# Protect image in browser php

Tags: javascript, php, html, encryption

I have image in my page, which I want to protect by directly viewing from it's URL.
Basically, I want to hide/encrypt image source.

```
<img src="www.mywebsite.com/media/1.jpg" alt="customer_id" />
```

I have disabled right click on the image by some sort of javascript. But, still one can get the image source from source code of the page.

I also tried by adding these attribute in image.

```
ondrag="return false"
ondragstart="return false"
oncontextmenu="return false"
galleryimg="no"
onmousedown="return false"
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of hiding the image source?

Comment: Not really.  If you're using HTML, the source is there on their computer somewhere and possible to look at.  At best, you'll be able to obscure it from *novice* users.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18870937/ specifically the accepted answer. Do it serverside. JS can always be disabled.

Comment: I want to protect it just because those are customer's ID (license, passport, etc.)

Comment: Not possible. Exactly how could the browser display the image in the first place if you've mangled the urls? And would stop someone from just fetching the raw html and poking around inside it without every loading it into a browser?

Comment: @MarcB: That's what I was wondering about. Is there any way to keep  user's data safe?

Comment: Protect it the same way you would any HTML content.  Write some PHP code that checks the auth cookie and verifies the user has permission to see that image, and if so, write out the image contents.  If not, respond with a 403.

Comment: Anyone with Firebug will be able to get at that image.  Failing that they can still take a sceenshot.  If you are trying to secure images accessible via browser, then your problem is with the people who have access to it.

Comment: I would'nt encourage you to continue cracking your brain to prevent image from been download. as far as I know if image is displayable on your page I will download it. other prevention could be that of watermarking . As Mike said your prevention could only work on Novice

Comment: You'd then have something like `<img src="getImage.php" />`

Comment: @MikeChristensen: That's a nice idea. I'll try with that. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeChristensen are you saying the images will render via php file

Comment: And if they are customer ID's, make sure they are not in a publicly accessible folder, even if you don't use the url to show them but serve them through php.

Comment: @RonakPatel: if you don't want something visible, then don't serve it up in the first place. it a viewer isn't authorized to see something, then don't display it. i.e. don't output the html for the image at all.

Comment: @jeroen: All sensitive images are in `windows azure's blob storage`. Is it ok?

Comment: @ShapCyber - Sure, browsers don't care about extension.  As long as the PHP code sets the correct MIME type and writes out valid bytes.

Comment: As long as they are not publicly accessible, even if you don't publish the url.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I agreed with you , but what about rendering the images with CSS

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to effectively hide it in HTML - but I think you are afraid that someone will see image that isn't his.
My solution: move images to directory that isn't reachable from the web, for example if now they are in

```
/home/mywebsite.com/public_html/media/
```

move them into:

```
/home/mywebsite.com/media/
```

and serve them via PHP:

```
if($userIsLogged && $imageBelongsToUser) { //this is of cource pseudo code - only showing the idea

 header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
 $image=imagecreatefromjpeg('/home/mywebsite.com/media/1.jpg');
 imagejpeg($image);

}else{
 echo "error";
}
```

of course you must somehow store information about pair user/image.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this.  Consider that your user could just open the tools panel of their browser and look at the URL that is sent over the wire.

If you really want to protect your source images, route them all through a single URL endpoint, say http:/mysite.com/img-gateway, and let the (possibly encrypted) POST data determine the image that will be returned.   Of course the user could always save your image and repub at another URL, but at least that will stop hot-linking.  Or, use a server extension of some kind that will respond with 403 Forbidden if a specific cookie is not present.